# How can I cast a generic type to another generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am in the process of converting from one ORM (Lightspeed) to another (Entity Framework).

Lightspeed classes descend from the Entity base class while the EF classes implement IEntity

At the moment I have the following generic types in the repository:

```
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : Entity { ... }
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll_EF<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity { ... }
```

Example usage would be

```
var claims = repository.GetAll<Claim>();  // Lightspeed
var users = repository.GetAll_EF<User>();  // EF
```

I want to have a single public method that calls the appropriate more specific method.
Something like

```
    public static  IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity))) // lightspeed
        {
            return GetAll_LS<TEntity>();
        }
        else
        if (typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity))) // EF
        {
            return GetAll_EF<TEntity>();
        }
        else throw new NotImplementedException("xxx");
    }
```

This gives the compiler errors

> The type 'TEntity' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'EfMigrationUtils.GetAll_LS()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TEntity' to 'Mindscape.LightSpeed.Entity'.

> The type 'TEntity' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'EfMigrationUtils.GetAll_EF()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TEntity' to 'Eml.Repository.Base.Abstract.IEntity'.

I want some way to tell the compiler that Claim is Entity, and user is IEntity.

Comment: "I want to have a single public method that calls the appropriate more specific method." Why? How does this help your migration?

Comment: With a single method like this, you can't without using reflection to call `GetAll_XX`. Why does this need to be one method? I'd suggest that naming conventions of `Entity` and `IEntity` are also poor since it's not clear what the differences are.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lightspeed or EF, but if they provide an overload for getting all the entities, that takes a `Type`, you can call that directly, instead of your `GetAll_LS` and `GetAll_EF` methods.

Comment: IMHO just rename the methods so they have the same name. The compiler will find the right method based on generic constraints. Your source code won't need to change when you later migrate a class from `:Entity` to `:IEntity`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - you cannot overload methods based solely on generic type constraints.

Comment: @sweeper Currently the repository is using

public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : Entity

I want to change this to 

public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class so that I can migrate the classes to EF without changing method calls everywhere..  I have edited the question to try and make it more obvious.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use `Cast` method.

```cs
if (typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity))) // lightspeed
{
    return GetAll_LS<Entity>().Cast<TEntity>();
}
else
if (typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity))) // EF
{
    return GetAll_EF<IEntity>().Cast<TEntity>();
}
else throw new NotImplementedException("xxx");
```

Comment: The issue is not in casting the return value to TEntity, it is in casting TEntity to Entity or IEntity